How to make menu with bordered active item only from 3 sides?
My menu has 2 borders: the main vertical border on the right of the whole menu and the border (top, bottom, left) of the active item. The right border of the active item should be empty. The main border should be interrupted in the same place where the active item right border was interrupted. Note that any of the items could be active, that is why the main border interruption can't be hardcoded


.container {
  border-right: 1px solid;
  width: 200px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.item {
  padding: 10px;
}

.active {
  border-top: 1px solid;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  border-left: 1px solid;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="item active">
    Test1
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    Test2
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    Test3
  </div>
</div>





At best you can switch the right border to the menu items - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/QWRdWRB Your right border is on the container and you can't hide that for a child item...

You can add a box-shadow for the right part to hide the border.


.container {
  border-right: 1px solid;
  width: 200px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.item {
  padding: 10px;
}

.active {
  border-top: 1px solid;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  border-left: 1px solid;
  box-shadow: 1px 0px 0px 0px white;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="item active">
    Test1
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    Test2
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    Test3
  </div>
</div>




You can't "interrupt" a border of a container for a specific child.
The only option is to "hide" that section of the border with a colored border on the child over that border section.
I'd suggest a positioned pseudo-element with the same background at the background of the container.


.container {
  border-right: 1px solid;
  width: 200px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.item {
  padding: 10px;
}

.item.active {
  border-top: 1px solid;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  border-left: 1px solid;
  position: relative;
}

.item.active::after {
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  width: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -1px;
  background: white;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="item active">
    Test1
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    Test2
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    Test3
  </div>
</div>




I honestly prefer your result since I have 2px missing using a box-shadow.

To achieve this behavior, set the active element's background to an opaque color and set the width of active element to:
containerWidth - padding * 2

With containerWidth being width of the parent container element and padding the padding size of active element. In this case its 180px:


.container {
  border-right: 1px solid;
  width: 200px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.item {
  padding: 10px;
}

.active {
  border-top: 1px solid;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  border-left: 1px solid;
  width: 180px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="item active">
    Test1
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    Test2
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    Test3
  </div>
</div>




You can add the margin-right: -1px; and background: white; into the .active class CSS.


const items = document.querySelectorAll('.item');

function RemoveActive() {
  for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (items[i].classList.contains('active')) {
      items[i].classList.remove('active');
    }
  }
}

for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  items[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    RemoveActive();
    items[i].classList.add('active');
  })
}
.container {
  width: 200px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  position: relative;
  border-right: 1px solid;
}

.item {
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.active {
  border-top: 1px solid;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  border-left: 1px solid;
  margin-right: -1px;
  background: white;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="item active">
    Test1
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    Test2
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    Test3
  </div>
</div>




Note that instead of making a whole  removeActive function, you can just select get the .active element and remove its class, example : document.getElementsByClassName("active")[0].classList.remove("active");

The below solution will work for your use case but the item needs to have a background-color and It won't work for the background-color: transparent.


.container {
  width: 200px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  border-right:1px solid black
}

.item {
  width: 179px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: white;
}

.active {
  border-top: 1px solid;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  border-left: 1px solid;
  border-right:1px solid rgba(0,0,0, 0.0)
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="item active">
    Test1
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    Test2
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    Test3
  </div>
</div>




To get the expected output rewrite the above styles :


.container {
  width: 200px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  border-right:1px solid black
}

.item {
  width: 179px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.item:first-child {
  border-right: 1px solid white;  
}

.active {
  border-top: 1px solid;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  border-left: 1px solid;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="item active">
    Test1
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    Test2
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    Test3
  </div>
</div>




I've thought about it but it doesn't fit me cause I need right border for menu to the full menu height https://jsfiddle.net/z5tk40ru/

@Kvasimodo Please check now will this work now #CSS #HTML

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
